# How do I turn an image into a vector on the iPhone like Adobe Illustrator's Live Trace?

Tags: iphone, vector

I want to be able to create vector files like Illustrator does on the iPhone. Does anyone know of an algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for each pixel try to grow by testing against it's neighbours for colour similarity with a threshhold. keep growing until no more expansion is possible due to threshold then you make a path using the outermost border pixels. Now repeat for the other pixels in the orignal raster image which were not already included in your previous expansions.

Comment: That is so cool. I thought this stuff died with Adobe Streamline.

Comment: Good suggestion, PeanutPower. Downloaded the AutoTrace code myself just for fun and got it to build and run in an iPhone app. Looks just like what the OP asked for. Very nice! You should get the bounty IMHO. ;-)

Comment: Matt, how did you get the AutoTrace code to build for iPhone?